# Air Android - StageWebView and URLLoader cache

Tags: android, cookies, air, urlloader, stagewebview

I'm using StageWebView in an Air (3.6) for Android app to let a user grant access to his account via OAuth.
After that I'm using a URLLoader to get the access token and account info.

That works on `Air for Desktop` but not on `Air for Android`.
It looks like the URLLoader can't access the cookie/cache to verify that the user has already logged in.
I'm totally stuck with this - why does it work on `Air for Desktop` but not on `Air for Android`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are handled differently across mobile and desktop platforms because of different network stacks. On Desktop and on ios, StageWebView shares cookies with URLLoader. On Android, StageWebView does not share cookies with URLLoader.

Visit this Adobe [tech note](http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/stagewebview-differences-platforms-air-sdk.html) for more info (scroll to bottom.)